# Проблема с импортом контрагентов в 1С УТ 11.3

Tags: 1с

Есть задача перенести в 1С УТ справочник контрагентов из другой (несовместимой) системы. Пытаюсь сделать это через <kbd>Начальное заполнение</kbd> --> <kbd>Загрузка данных из файла</kbd> --> <kbd>Контрагенты</kbd>, вставляю импортируемые данные из буфера. Дальнейшие действия не приводят к нужному результату, т.к. 1С не нравится то, что я ей пихаю в полях **Партнёр** и **Юр/Физлицо** (я пихаю текст).

Пример вставляемой строки:

```
Департамент дорожного благоустройства и строительства   7021056342  0               702101001           Департамент дорожного благоустройства и строительства   ЮЛ  0           пр-кт Ленина, 46-1
```

Если в остальных полях есть хинты с типами данных, то в этих нет. Что требуется указывать в этих полях?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая версия УТ?

Comment: @Mikhail, 11 версия

Comment: Что-то не вижу там вообще такого, у меня 11.1

Comment: @Mikhail добавил скриншот

Comment: Понятно, это 11.3, свежайшая, я ещё не открывал её даже. По идее, в правом верхнем углу (на скриншоте перекрыто другим окном) должна быть кнопка со знаком "?" - это справка ;)

Comment: Кстати, красненькие уголки в углах ячеек говорят о том, что хинты таки есть.

Comment: Хинты есть, но, как я упомянул, они не информативны.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46964/discussion-between-mikhail-sibirev-and-anatol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью @Mikhail Sibirev разобрался.

> ЮрФизЛицо нужно указывать как один из этих вариантов:
>   Юридическое лицо
>   Физическое лицо
>   Юр. лицо, за пределами РФ
>   Индивидуальный предприниматель
>   - именно так, с пробелами и пунктуацией

С партнёром сложнее - для заполнения этого поля необходимо предварительно заполнить справочник партнёров, а там тоже есть своя особенность - поле Юр/Физлицо может принимать только значения `Компания` или `Частное лицо`. Так же поля клиент и поставщик не корректно распознают цифровые значения, пришлось указывать `Да` и `Нет`.
После заполнения справочника партнёров можно возвращаться к контрагентам и в поле Партнёр указывать наименование партнёра, как в справочнике. Тогда они проассоциируются и всё пройдёт без ошибок.